# get alerts when capturechange Mysql of Nifi fails

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, data-warehouse

My Nifi Flow starts with capturechangeMysql processor.
I am trying to enhance my flows by adding email alerts whenever a processor fails.
I understand I can use PutEmail for this purpose.
my flow fails most of the time at the capturechangeMysql because of Binlogs or connections or some other random issues.
My thinking is to create a link out of failure relationship of this processor to PutEmail, But there is no failure relationship for this processor. (It only has success relation.)

In this scenario how can i alert when there is a failure in capturechangeMysql processor ?

Please share your thoughts or if i am missing something or other alternatives.